# Java get actual generic parameters

Tags: java, generics, parameters

I'm using java 7. When trying to extract the actual generic parameters of a  derived class I use the following code :

```
Class<E> cls = (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType)   
                  getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

It usually works well, but if I have the case of a multiple inheritance ( C extends B extends A ) and B is also abstract (not yet declaring the actual generic parameters) I recursively get the class before the base one (B) and use this method on B (instead of getClass()) [since if I had used it on C, its superclass wouldn't be a parameterizedType], and the actual type arguments show me generic types (I get T for using this).

If anyone encountered this I'd appreciate any help or guidelines.

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the actual generic parameters of a derived class?

Comment: Note that 'C extends B extends A' is not multiple inheritance, which is 'C extends B and A'

Comment: Yeah it's not a multiple inheritance (which doesn't exist in java 7), that's why I added the explanation in parenthesis. My whole case is a base class which many classes are derived from, I want to do an action with the actual generic in all of those classes.. but some classes are not directly derived from that class (there's that B class in the middle) in which case the extraction of the actual parameter retrieves T instead of the actual parameters.

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: The question is how to get the actual type of a generic inside a method of a class which has a subtype which has a subtype and the declaration of the generic is only in the most subtype class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that generics are invariant. As you say, it usually works well, but come inheritance - you are in trouble...

For any two distinct types A and B, `Class<A>` is neither a subtype nor a
supertype of `Class<B>` [JLS, 4.10].

Comment: Yeah but class B<actual> extends class A<T> and I want to find actual from a method in A. This case works but if there's C<T> extends A<T> and above B extends C, it doesn't work.

Comment: Might I suggest some code addition for test purposes that will make your debugging life easier in this case. Chain .getClass().getGenericSuperclass() twice in a row and give it a go with the problematic inheritance chain to see if it will pass. It it indeed passes, code a workaround for long chains of inheritance.

Comment: I did getSuperclass.getGenericSuperclass and it got me T, which is the generic declaration in C, that's where my problem is, I did a loop of getting super classes until it reaches the one I wanted this way.. And I don't seem to get the actual generic this way. Seems like it only works with direct subtypes...